# Saving text area into mySQL database field PHP

Tags: php, mysql, post, textarea

Hi i am using openWYSIWYG as a text editor for a text area. I then am trying to post the contents of the text area to a field in my database.

This is the code i have so far -

```
<?php
$text = $_GET['Comments']; 



mysql_connect ("localhost", "user", "password") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("databasename") or die ('Data error:' . mysql_error());

$query="INSERT INTO KeepData (player_data)VALUES ('$text')";

mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database' . mysql_error());




?>
```

I can connect to the database, and when i click submit it adds a blank entry into the field? how would i get it so it keeps all the formatted data?

Many thanks

*update*

```
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
 <textarea id="Comments" name="Comments">
 example text
 </textarea>
<input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Save Post" />
 </form>
```

DIM3NSION

Comment: This is not gonna be considered 'good practise' by the SQL Injection mafia.

Comment: Just to say, you should not use the old mysql api anymore, it is deprecated for many years now and eventually will disappear from php. Use PDO instead.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like the following:

```
<?php
    if ($_POST['submit']) {
        mysql_connect ("localhost", "user", "password") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("databasename") or die ('Data error:' . mysql_error());
        $text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comments']); 
        $query="INSERT INTO KeepData (player_data) VALUES ('$text')";
        mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database' . mysql_error());
    }
?>


<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <textarea name="comments">Example Comment</textarea>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply i have tried this but again it adds a blank field. Ive updated my post with my form information. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: use this and change $text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comments']);

Comment: What output do you get if you echo $query?

Comment: Check the data type in your database table.

Answer (score 0):

You must save an format coded version elsewhere on a hidden textarea (much like here on StackOverflow, if you type `**text**` it will come out as **text**, in the database, they probably save it as `**text**` and render it with PHP.

Once the formatted version is saved, render it with PHP when you get the data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Is your form POSTing or GETing (you said POSTing in your post)? You have $_GET['Comments'], but if your form's action is POST, you need to use $_POST['Comments'];

if you add `echo $text;exit;` after you assign $text, do you see anything?

Comment: Or just use REQUEST

Answer (score 0):

You should use [mysql_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function because of mysql injection and if text contains `'` you'll get error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if your have `<form action='get'>`. If it is just `<form>` `get` used by default
2. Check that your wisywig have `name='Comments'` attribute.
3. Escape the `$text` with `mysql_real_escape_string`. It can contain SQL-illegal symbols, like `'`. This function escapes them with `\`
4. (recommendation) do not use `mysql_*`, it is deprecated of PHP 5.3 and will be removed.
5. (recommendation) appending user input to sql query is always a risk of SQL-injection. Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php)

Answer (score 0):

just add the onclick event something like

```
<button onclick=" $('#txtEditor').val($('.Editor-editor').html());" type="Publish" id="Publish" name="Publish" class="btn btn-primary">Publish</button>
```

remember the `#txtEditor` has to match with the form id, this works well, and note the `.html` will save it to database with the color,Bold and many more effect if you added any (that is the wysiwyg fuction)

then for your php code that send to database, do something like this

```
$anything = ($_POST['txtEditor']);
```

`$anything` you which to use as variable,dont forget the `txtEidtor` is the form id. with this your wysiwyg is up and working.